# Release backing layer for a view to reclaim memory?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios, uiview, core-animation

I have a custom tab widget, with a lot of views whose backing CALayer objects are taking up too much memory. I'm looking at releasing views for background tabs, but it would be simpler if I could just ask the framework to release the backing CALayer (which is where most of the memory is going) and have it re-create it on demand. Is that possible?

Does a nested view hierarchy consume more memory than a flatter one, because there are more CALayer objects, with mostly the same pixels? If a 100 x 100 view takes X memory, does it mean that a 100 x 100 view with a 100x100 subview takes roughly 2X?

Why didn't Apple go with the AppKit model where the programmer controls which views have backing Core Animation layers? That would consume a lot less memory, which is scarce on iOS compared to OS X. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All views are layer-backed on iOS and you have no control over this.

You should just release the inactive views and reload them as necessary.

The reason views are layer-backed on iOS is so that the GPU does the majority of the heavy lifting. This massively reduces the CPU load so that the CPU can be used for real work or be throttled down to save power.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I was trying to say that when the subviews of a given view are not independently animated or moved around, and are all opaque, is there a need to have separate layers for each of them, as opposed to just one for the parent view? In any case, thanks for your answer.